# Building corpus from PubMed Central

Tags: pubmed

I am trying to develop a retrieval system for which a corpus is required. Since PubMed hosts many free articles, I decided to use it. However, now I found out that PubMed central has licensing [restrictions](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/openftlist/).

Since my intention is to release the corpus formally along with my software (which obviously is not related to biology and I am not using the publications scientifically), I believe that any license will do. However, I don't want to take any chances. Can anyone tell me which license to use in PubMed?

Comment: Is the idea to redistribute papers downloaded from pubmed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I would like to redistribute as it is